# Basement remodeling cost

Tags: basement

I am currently hiring for a ~550 sqft basement (semi-finished) remodeling job. We are planning on adding drywall, insulation, redoing our suspended ceiling, adding a bathroom and a designated laundry area. We are also adding windows. We are going with an Owens Corning system. Our current estimate that one of the contractors has given us is ~$55000(all materials included). Is this the going rate?

Comment: going rate for what? ... you provided no details

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are in no position to give you information on pricing here

Comment: In general, we can't compare pricing (for a bunch of reasons). But if you have specific pieces to ask, we *might* be able to help guide you. Some key issues though with getting an overall price: Location (US vs. other countries, where in the US, etc.) affects labor costs, local rules can significantly affect costs on electrical, plumbing, etc.,  half bath vs. full bath, does adding windows mean digging window wells, knocking holes in thewall, etc.,  what level of finish (bare drywall, paint, wallpaper, etc.) etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to answer this question as it's like asking what is the going rate for a car? But to give you an idea of a semi-DIY job I did about 4 years ago for the exact size basement remodel but with all 6 walls concrete (below garage), it cost me about $3,000 in labor (framing + drywall + tile), including lumber and sheetrock. The framer was an acquaintance so probably gave me a little break, maybe 20% off the usual rate.

I did the rest by myself, including the insulation (foamboards+roxul), electric/lights (researched code extensively while doing and had it checked for code), painting, engineered wood floors, etc. All these cost me probably 10-12k in materials. The flooring (~2k), insulation, electrical components, door and a couple of windows (~2k) as this space originally had a garage door, were the most expensive parts. Also, this is my office/gameroom so I went with a bit of an industrial look. There was no ductwork in this space so I added a split air AC. If you need to finish the ductwork/ceiling, this will undoubtedly add to your cost of labor and materials.

So I want to estimate the entire project at around $15k. It took me about 3-4 months (while also having a day job and working on other parts of the house) and it was quite an enjoyable process (if it is your thing). The construction industry is VERY busy right now. You'd be lucky to get a callback, and the prices quoted are in general very high because most professionals who do improvement have work lined up for the entire year! In that climate, you will get quoted a high price. If you are able to at all DIY at least some parts of it, you will save a LOT of money.

Since you are posting in DIY, I assume you are at least open to it. Prepare for long hours of youTube watching, code reading, and learning by asking specific questions about narrow issues (unlike this very question). YouTube can be tricky, so ALWAYS read comments on those, even if a video is seemingly by a pro, because you will find many of those "pros" make serious mistakes and some downright dangerous. So make sure YouTube, forums, and Q/As are not your only source of information. Many of the codes are actually published so I'd start there.

Sorry, I cannot help you anymore since your question is very broad but if you want to ask me specifics on certain parts of the project I did, I'd be happy to answer if I can.

Here are some photos of the finishing stages for inspiration.

David

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]